# Yii: To show Image in CGridView column based on database value

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to show a ticked image if my value if set to Y. I followed [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26501-how-to-display-image-in-gridview-widget-based-on-db-field-value/) post but I get the following as contents of my grid column instead of the image:

```
<img src="/webapp/images/tickedS.jpg" alt="" />
```

Following is my model code for the new method that I wrote:

```
    public function getSurgeryFlaged(){
    return $this->flag_for_dashboard=='Y' ?  CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl .'/images/tickedS.jpg') : '';  

}
```

Following is column option for CGridView :

```
'SurgeryFlag'=>array('name'=>'Flag','value'=>'$data->surgeryFlaged','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'50')),
```

Instead of Model property, if I create a Controller protected method, the result is the same. Kindly guide, what am I doing wrong...?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Faisal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'raw' as the type. see [CFormatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter)

raw: the attribute value will not be changed at all.

```
'SurgeryFlag'=>array(
   'type'=>'raw',
   'name'=>'Flag',
   'value'=>'$data->surgeryFlaged',
   'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'50')),
```